# How do I exclude unchanged fields in Flashback query resultset?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c, flashback

Is it possible to exclude unchanged fields in Flashback query resultset?

Consider I have following table

```
create table first_table
(
    id int generated as identity,
    name NVARCHAR2(1024),
    age smallint,
    notebook nclob,
    userpic clob,
    salary float
)
```

If the table has very frequent updates (e.g. on `notebook` field) following versioned query

```
select ROWID, VERSIONS_OPERATION, VERSIONS_STARTSCN, VERSIONS_STARTTIME, VERSIONS_XID, id, name, age, notebook, userpic, salary
from FIRST_TABLE versions between scn 1469193 and 1482882;
```

will pull heavy userpic value for every row even though it's the same.

Can I somehow avoid that and instead get NULLs for unchanged values ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `LAG()` Analytic Function in order to compare a column's value for the current row with the previous row. So, pick any column's value unmatched its value of LAG to display only the changes while keeping others NULL as

```
SELECT versions_starttime, f.ID, f.name, f.age,
       CASE WHEN NVL(TO_CHAR(f.notebook),' ') != 
                 NVL(LAG(TO_CHAR(f.notebook)) OVER 
                     (PARTITION BY TO_CHAR(f.notebook) 
                          ORDER BY VERSIONS_STARTTIME NULLS FIRST),' ')
            THEN
                 f.notebook
             END AS notebook, 
       CASE WHEN NVL(TO_CHAR(f.userpic),' ') != 
                 NVL(LAG(TO_CHAR(f.userpic)) OVER 
                     (PARTITION BY TO_CHAR(f.userpic) 
                          ORDER BY VERSIONS_STARTTIME NULLS FIRST),' ')
            THEN
                 f.userpic
             END AS userpic,
       f.salary                       
  FROM first_table 
  VERSIONS BETWEEN SCN 1469193 AND 1482882 f
```

Comment: Thank you, Barbaros! I'll profile this approach. I wonder what the performance implications of doing such check on every column of a table with very high throughput of changes. It may happen that downloading "useless" fields and discarding them on the client becomes faster.

Comment: you're welcome @expert , tell me about the difference in terms of performance with the current case.